# VBA function returns #VALUE in excel with the message: A value in the formula is off the wrong data type

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am a just beginning to learn VBA. I am trying to do a loop that will act as a solver to find the number of payments for a loan:

```
Function FonctionValue(rate As Double, pmt1 As Double, loan As Double, nbpmt As Double)

    FonctionValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.pmt(rate, nbpmt, loan) - pmt1

End Function

Function Npmt(nbpmtlow As Double, nbpmthigh As Double, rate As Double, loan As Double, pmt1 As Double) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nbpmt As Double

    For i = 1 To 100

        flow = FonctionValue(rate, pmt1, loan, nbpmtlow)
        fhigh = FonctionValue(rate, pmt1, loan, nbpmthigh)
        value = nbpmtlow - flow * (nbpmthigh - nbpmtlow) / (fhigh - flow)
        fnbpmt = FonctionValue(rate, pmt1, loan, nbpmt)

        If fhigh * fnbpmt > 0 Then
            nbpmthigh = value
        Else
            nbpmtlow = value
        End If

    Next i

    value = Npmt

End Function
```

Comment: What is going wrong? can you provide test data and expected output?  Does the code error?  If so, what line?

Comment: What is `Npmt` supposed to return? Shouldn't the last line be `Npmt = value`?

Comment: Confused as to why you wouldn't just use the built in VBA [NPer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/nper-function) or  `WorksheetFunction.NPer`.

Comment: Npmt is supposed to return the number of payments but I want to do it without using the NPer function. No line is giving me an error but when I enter the function in excel I get hashtagVALUE and the message when I hover with my mouse over the cell is: A value is of the wrong data type. For example if I enter 10 as the low number of payments, 30 as the high number of payments, 3% as the rate, 50 000 as the loan and -3137.37 as payment(pmt1) the answer should be 22 or close to 22.

Comment: In the line `fnbpmt = FonctionValue(rate, pmt1, loan, nbpmt)`, the `nbpmt` is 0, which is not a valid number of payments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issues:

- In the line `fnbpmt = FonctionValue(rate, pmt1, loan, nbpmt)`, `nbmpt` = 0. This is an invalid input to `WorksheetFunction.Pmt`. It's not immediately clear what `nbpmt` should be, but it must be greater than 0.
- Change `value = Npmt` to `Npmt = Value`; you have the order backwards.